# OpenCart - Journal theme V2.7.6 ,Superfilter for mobile

Tags: opencart2.x, journal

I am using superfilter on Journal theme V2.7.6 , It is not loaded on mobile, I've searched the codes looking where the condition of loading it without luck.
How can I load it on the mobile version?